# Fetch new entries from MySQL database automatically in Java every n milliseconds

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to create an ordering application in Java where the user places an order, specifying the products. The combination of the order's timestamp and customer's id is unique. What I'm trying to do is to check for new orders every few seconds(or milliseconds), fetch the new orders and then create the corresponding objects. I have an ArrayList of orders in which, each Order has an ArrayList of Products, a timestamp and a customer id.
I send queries to the DB every 700ms in order to retrieve the new orders and create the Objects.

My problem is that sometimes, the query doesn't return the new order, that is, the new entries in the DB. I tried various values for the milliseconds but if it's to small, the program creates two or even more Order objects. I want to exactly one order Object for every new entry.

Here's the code:

```
DBConnect db = new DBConnect();
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = 
Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
String today = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd").format(new Date());
today = today + " 00:00:00";
ArrayList<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();

db.connect();


executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {   
            String now = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());

            try
            {
                String query = "SELECT DISTINCT last_edit, customer_id, employee_username, closed\r\n" + 
                        "FROM orders\r\n" + 
                        "WHERE last_edit = '" + now + "' ORDER BY last_edit";

                ResultSet rs = db.getStatement().executeQuery(query);

                while(rs.next())
                    orders.add(new Order(rs.getString("last_edit"), rs.getString("customer_id"), rs.getString("employee_username"), rs.getString("closed")));
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }

            try
            {
                String query = "SELECT last_edit, product.id AS product_id,\r\n" + 
                        "quantity_weight,\r\n" + 
                        "orders.price\r\n" + 
                        "FROM customer, product, orders\r\n" + 
                        "WHERE orders.customer_id = customer.id\r\n" + 
                        "AND orders.product_id = product.id\r\n" +
                        "AND last_edit = '" + now + "' ORDER BY last_edit";

                ResultSet rs = db.getStatement().executeQuery(query);

                for(Order order: orders)
                {
                    while(rs.next())
                        if(order.getLast_edit().equals(rs.getString("last_edit")))
                        {
                            order.getProducts().add(new Product(rs.getString("product_id"), rs.getString("quantity_weight"), rs.getString("orders.price")));
                            System.out.println(order.getLast_edit());
                        }


                    rs.beforeFirst();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
    }, 0, 700, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using equality `=` insteed of `>=` condition is a mistery to me. Besides that you relay on system timestamp insteed of timestamp of last newest order. In edge cases multiple orders can have the same timestamp and this could get you it a trouble. I assume that you ahve autoincrement primary key set in your table, so you should rely on id (your pk), that is guaranteed to be unique, insteed of timestamp. Your process would look like this:

1. Fetch list of all orders - process them and take max PK from selected orders
2. `SELECT (whatever) FROM (somewhere) WHERE order.id > lastSavedId`
3. Process new orders, save max id and wait whatever you want
4. Go to 2. repeat